# SwiftUI Video player how to set url

Tags: swift, swiftui, video-player

I am trying to create a view that allows me to send a URL of the video I want to play. My view looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct PlayerView: View {
    var videoURL : String
    private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")!)

var body: some View {
    VideoPlayer(player: player)
        .onAppear() {
            // Start the player going, otherwise controls don't appear
            player.play()
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            // Stop the player when the view disappears
            player.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

If try to set the URL to the passed parameter I get this error:

```
Cannot use instance member 'videoURL' within property initializer; property initializers run     before 'self' is available
```

How do I pass aURL to the View to play different movies?

---

I changed my code as suggested and the video does not play:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct PlayerView: View {
    var videoURL : String
    @State private var player : AVPlayer?

var body: some View {
    VideoPlayer(player: player)
        .onAppear() {
            // Start the player going, otherwise controls don't appear
            guard let url = URL(string: videoURL) else {
                return
            }
            print(url)
            let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            self.player = player
            self.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            self.player!.play()
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            // Stop the player when the view disappears
            player?.pause()
        } 
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the video on the timer. I tried this:

```
} else {
    VideoPlayer(player: viewModel.player)
    .onAppear {
          viewModel.urlString = "https://testsite.neumont.edu/images/green.mp4"

                        }

    .onReceive(movieSwitchTimer) { _ in
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
      viewModel.urlString = "https://testsite.neumont.edu/images/earth.mp4"
                            }
    self.activeImageIndex = (self.activeImageIndex + 1) % slideStore.images.count
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, but since you're already using `onAppear`, that seems like a good place to accomplish this:

```
struct PlayerView: View {
    var videoURL : String
    @State private var player : AVPlayer?
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .onAppear() {
                // Start the player going, otherwise controls don't appear
                guard let url = URL(string: videoURL) else {
                    return
                }
                let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                self.player = player
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear() {
                // Stop the player when the view disappears
                player?.pause()
            }
    }
}
```

You'll want `player` to be `@State` because it should persist between renders of the view.

**Update, based on comments, handling a scenario where the URL may change**:

```
class VideoViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var urlString : String? {
        didSet {
            guard let urlString = urlString, let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                return
            }
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            player.seek(to: .zero)
            player.play()
        }
    }
    var player = AVPlayer()
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = VideoViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: viewModel.player)
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.urlString = "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    viewModel.urlString = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IMG_0226", withExtension: "mp4")!.absoluteString
                }
            }
    }
}
```

In the update, you can see that I store the player in an `ObservableObject`. Any time the url string gets changed, it reloads the player. The `onAppear` is not necessary in your code -- it's just a way to show loading different videos at different times (the first being the URL you provided, the second being a URL from my bundle).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still no video. see my changes in the question

Comment: I just tried the code that you pasted in your update using the URL from your original example and it is loading fine for me. iOS 14.4, Xcode 12.4. Have you tried just loading from a blank ContentView with nothing else running in the project to see if anything else is effecting it?

Comment: It works now for me on the first video, but the second video I pass does not display

Comment: What "second video"? Your question doesn't mention anything about that. I made an assumption since you were already using onAppear (which would only be triggered once) and the fact that your question never mentions anything else that the url parameter won't change. But are you saying that the URL parameter may change?

Comment: sorry, yes I would like to play several different videos. Is there a better way?

Comment: Added another example with your new requirements.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, but that last example was confusing to me.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is confusing about it?

Comment: I added some more code. my requirement is to display images and videos on a timer. I tried to change the url in the timer.

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering with your code? You didn’t include all of it, so I can’t run it.

Comment: I separated my code into another project and your suggestion worked! I sure appreciate you kindness to help me.